# Example of Finite Group and Homomorphism

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-homomorphism

I'm new to Math Stack Exchange.

I saw a problem about a finite group, $G$, and a homomorphism that maps an element of $G$ onto another element of $G$ (the mapping doesn't necessarily have to be to a distinct element).

What exactly might this look like? Could someone give a super trivial example of what this would be?

Comment: Send every element of $G$ to the identity element.

Comment: yeah but what could $G$ look like? What exactly is a finite group?

Answer (score 0):

Take $G = \{0\}$, the trivial group. Define $f \colon G \rightarrow G$ by $f(0) = 0$.

Take $G = {0,1}$ $0+0 = 0$, $1+0 = 0+1 = 1$, $1+1 = 0$. Take $f \colon G \rightarrow G$ by $f(0) = 0$, $f(1) = 1$.

Comment: what about a group with more than $1$ element?

Comment: @plottwist added an edit

Comment: so is it just ${0,1}$ and addition is defined as normal addition modulo 2?

Comment: @plottwist yes it is

Comment: could the numbers ${0, 1, 2, 3, 4 \cdots 99}$ be a finite group in which addition is characterized as normal addition mod 100?

Comment: @plottwist yeah, as a matter of fact, take any positive integer n, and you get a finite group just like the way you did it!

Comment: oh okay that makes sense! thanks!